# jade convert list into table

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm learning node.js and trying to creating an app.  I'm having problems changing a jade list into a table.  Here is the code I'm trying to convert

```
h3.
    Students
  ul
    each student, i in studentlist
      li#student_list_item
        a(href='#') #{student.student} lives at #{student.street} #{student.city}, #{student.state}
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
h3.
  Students
table.table.table-condensed.table-hover
  th Name
  th Address
  th City
  th State
  th GPA
each student, i in studentlist
  td#student_list_item
    td= student.student
    td= student.street
    td= student.city
    td= student.state
    td= student.gpa
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want a new table row for each student?  (And for the top row).

```
tr#student_list_item
```

instead of

```
td#student_list_item
```

Comment: Just tried that. No changes. Data just shows up all on 1 line.

Comment: Also, make sure the "each" is inside the table.  (i.e. indent the each)